# How can I correct MySQL replication while using federated tables?

Tags: mysql, replication

This is an overview of what I have going
I have 2 server A (10.0.4.22) AND B (10.0.4.29)
A is a replication of B and B is a replication of A (yes it is a ring replication)

ON A I have 2 table uat and ge.
uat have all Innodb engine base tables NO federated tables.
And a database called ge have many InnoDB table and some FEDERATED tables. These federated tables are pointing to the database uat on the same server (A via a connection called accordion)

Now, I have created a connection on A like so

```
CREATE SERVER accordion
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER uat
OPTIONS (USER 'fed_user', HOST '10.0.4.22', PORT 3306, DATABASE 'uat', password 'myPass');
```

Since the statement CREATE SERVER is not replicated due to FEDERATED table limitation I had to create it manually on B as well like so

```
CREATE SERVER accordion
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER uat
OPTIONS (USER 'fed_user', HOST '10.0.4.29', PORT 3306, DATABASE 'uat', password 'myPass');
```

Please notice that both connections have different IP addresses. each server points to itself.

The issue is that the replication breaks. I tried to execute

```
1) start the server using SKIP-SLAVE-START
2) SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
3) START SLAVE;
4) 5 seconds later MySQL service stop working.
```

When I look at the .err file I don't see any sine of crash.

I also tried turning on core-file but there was no core file created. It is a silent crash I am not sure how to figure out what is causing this issue? What Can I do to fix the problem and bring the replication back up?

Here are my theory.
When I issue an update statement on a federated table located on A then the server will make the update to the table after connecting to the remote table using the first accordion string I created.

But when the the replication tries to make the update on the SLAVE "B" it sees duplicate records so the replication breaks. But the only thing that is not adding up is ROW REPLICATION. since I am using ROW base replication then the update query itself is not replicated but the row changes are applied to the slave. However, if I don't have accordion string on the slave. The slave will give an error. which tells me that the query itself may be replicated and not the ROW changes.

Comment: 3 users voted to close this question but no one left a comment on why!